# "newly-springing-up technologies", is this phrase formed in the right manner?

Tags: phrase-request

I am writing a sentence like this:

Music at the turn of the twentieth century was trying to abandon the traditional rules and restrictions and to embrace the **newly-springing-up** technologies, but after the world-war-I people reallized that technology cannot solve all the problems and they then began to ridicule the meaninglessness of modernization.

I wander if the bolded phrase is right?

Comment: You mean you wonder if it is right. Your phrasing is somewhat heavy. You'd be better off with: noun that were [verb and adverb].

Comment: *-ly* adverbs are not normally hyphenated in compounds. So, even if you were to hyphenate *springing-up*, the compound phrase would be *newly springing-up technologies*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to hyphenate the elements of the phrase.  It would be better as a participial phrase modifier coming after the noun it modifies:

> ... to embrace the technologies newly springing up.

than as an adjective proper placed before the noun. Either that, or  a relative clause functioning adjectivally:

> ... to embrace the technologies that had newly sprung up.
>
> ... to embrace the technologies that had newly been springing up.

Your attempt, which makes the phrase into an attributive adjective, is not ungrammatical, but it is stylistically awkward.  In part that awkwardness is the result of the phrasal verb, **spring up**, and its intransitivity.

> He decided to do something about the **recently sprouting up** weeds. <sup>awkward</sup>

This would be stylistically fine:

> He decided do something about the weeds recently sprouting up.
>
> He wanted to join one of the **newly formed** clubs.
>
> He wanted to become a player on one of the **newly forming** teams.
>
> He didn't want to pay the recently **jacked up**  <sup>transitive</sup> prices.

although that last one is rather colloquial in its register.